# How to find average values using a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get the average of a specific station in a specific month for each individual layer.

So far I've tried this but the average value is incorrect:

```
istnspecific = emptystns.index('53959')
ilayer = 0
imon = 1-1
print istnspecific
a = data[istnspecific,imon, ilayer]
np.mean(a, dtype=np.float64)
```

Comment: post some input test data, and expcted result

Comment: input test data for the data file at the specific station for the specific month and layer would be

Comment: -8, -29, 123, -19 and the expected value is 16.75. The value the code prints is 15.886917808219179

Comment: what is the output of print(a) ?

Comment: numpy.mean([-8, -29, 123, -19]) always produces 16.75

Comment: @eshinner Please update the question with input test data and expected results. Not everybody skimming the question will get to reading the comments.